# Creating a java ArrayList instance of a generic type obtained dynamically from a classloader

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am trying to create an ArrayList that would have its generic type derived dynamically from a external pojo file.

Anyway to get this done ?

So far I have this -

```
File pojoJarFile = pojoJarFile = new File("C:/Test/my-pojo.jar");
URLClassLoader genericClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{pojoJarFile.toURI().toURL()});
Class genericClassRef = genericClassLoader.loadClass("com.mypackage.MyClass");
List<genericClassRef> listInstance = new ArrayList<genericClassRef>();
```

But its failed at compilation with the error -

> java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   class genericClassRef
> location: class qmo.kafka.test.harness.QmoKafkaMessageBuilder

Comment: Your list has to be defined as `List<Object>`.  You cannot put the actual type in the code, because you haven’t made that type available to the compiler.

Comment: This works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This code syntax is wrong, and, at the same time is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

You can write `List<MyClass> myList` but not `List<MyClass.class> myList` or
`Class c = MyList.class; List<c> myList` the class name which goes between the <> must be a class name known at compile time, and not a Class instance.

Moreover, generics are erased at runtime, so it is of no practical use to add an *unknown* type like that.

If the classes you load have some common interface which you know at compile time, you can use that.